# Adding an object to a collection: collection is declared in different class

Tags: c#, class, collections

```
class Family
{
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public Adults father { get; set; }
     public Adults mother { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }     
}

class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Adults : Person 
{
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public int LicNumber { get; set; }
}


class Program
{





    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Family> Families = new List<Family>();


        Adults father = new Adults { Name = "Jim", Age = 34, Job = "Programmer", LicNumber = 2344454 };
        Adults mother = new Adults { Name = "Amy", Age = 33, Job = "Nurse", LicNumber = 88888 };
        Family fam1 = new Family { Nickname = "Family One", FamilyId = 1, father = father, mother = mother ,    };
        Person child1 = new Person { Name = "Bob", Age = 4 }; 


        Families.Add(fam1);

        PrintFamily(fam1);  

    }

    private static void PrintFamily(Family family)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{family.Nickname} ({family.FamilyId})");
        Console.WriteLine("Prents : ");
        Console.WriteLine($"{family.father.Name} - {family.father.Job} - {family.father.LicNumber}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{family.mother.Name} - {family.mother.Job} {family.mother.LicNumber}");
        Console.WriteLine("Kids");
          Console.WriteLine($"( I WANT TO PRINT KIDS NAME AND AGE HERE, but it's not LETTING ME);

        //I want to print Kids information as well. Like I did it with parents.

        Console.ReadKey();
    }



}
```

My question is: how do I add Child1 to the Collection ? //Children collection in class Family? What did I do wrong here?  I created an object based on Person class, did input name and age info, but it's not letting me print the info of the child.

Answer (score 0):

In your "printFamily" method you never access the member properties of the child1 object. I recommend adding a second parameter for an object of type Person, then have another line of code that accesses the member properties of the Person object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
First inicialize Children List:

```
class Family   
{
 public int FamilyId { get; set; }
 public string Nickname { get; set; }
 public Adults father { get; set; }
 public Adults mother { get; set; }
 public List<Person> Children = new List<Person>();
}
```

Next add the Children :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<Family> Families = new List<Family>();


    Adults father = new Adults { Name = "Jim", Age = 34, Job = "Programmer", LicNumber = 2344454 };
    Adults mother = new Adults { Name = "Amy", Age = 33, Job = "Nurse", LicNumber = 88888 };
    Family fam1 = new Family { Nickname = "Family One", FamilyId = 1, father = father, mother = mother ,    };
    Person child1 = new Person { Name = "Bob", Age = 4 }; 

    fam1.Children.add(child1); //Here add child to collection

    Families.Add(fam1);

    PrintFamily(fam1);  

}
```

Next print Children list:

```
    private static void PrintFamily(Family family)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{family.Nickname} ({family.FamilyId})");
    Console.WriteLine("Prents : ");
    Console.WriteLine($"{family.father.Name} - {family.father.Job} - {family.father.LicNumber}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{family.mother.Name} - {family.mother.Job} {family.mother.LicNumber}");
    Console.WriteLine("Kids:");
    //read list and pirnt
     foreach(Person per in family.Children){
        Console.WriteLine($"{per.Name} ({per.Age})");
     }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: When I try to add new object to collection AKA CHILD1 , I get a compiler error
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: Observe that in the OP's code, the `Children` list is not instantiated so you'll get the problem described above. Edit your answer to show the initialization and your answer will work.

Comment: Fab - If you look carefully, I did initialize collection / list children in class Family.

Comment: Edit: now the Children list is instantiated. new List<Person>();

Comment: @FredYuldashev - I looked at your code. You don't initialize it.

Comment: @FredYuldashev lock my  answer you can see the initialization : public List<Person> Children = new List<Person>();